# Remove Row From Section

Tags: swift, uitableview, delete-row

This is my sectionArray

```
 var sectionArray = [Sections]()
```

This is how I figure out how many rows in section

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionArray[section].items.count
}
```

and this is my code to remove a row by sliding.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        sectionArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
        if sectionArray[indexPath.section].title.count == 0 {
            sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        //self.isEditing = false
        print("delete button tapped")
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return [delete]
}
```

Theoretically this delete stuff should work but I am getting error No exact matches in call to subscript at

```
sectionArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: you shout be removing an item from items property try `sectionArray[indexPath.section].items.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: it did remove the error but does not do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
/// This line
sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
/// should be like this
sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.section)
/// This line will remove the section from the table 
tableView.deleteSections(.init(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
```

You are using row to remove a section

**Edit**

Replace all the code you provided us with this

```swift
      /*
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            sectionArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
            if sectionArray[indexPath.section].title.count == 0 {
                sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            //self.isEditing = false
            print("delete button tapped")
        }
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return [delete]
    }
     */
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            //self.isEditing = false
            sectionArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            if sectionArray[indexPath.section].items.isEmpty {
                sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.section)
                tableView.deleteSections(.init(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
            }
        }
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return [delete]
    }
```

Comment: it did remove the error but does not do anything

Comment: You should add code to remove the section too, I'll edit my response

Comment: changed as you advised. Nothing. Just prints delete button tapped

Comment: Wait ! you are not calling the code to perform the delete action, I'll update my response

Comment: sorry but this one also does not do the trick

Comment: sectionArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row).    No exact matches in call to subscript

Comment: sectionArray[indexPath.section]. items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

You need to access to the items array to remove an item

Comment: yes, I realized that then approved your answer. Thanks